# MSBuild integration with Jenkins

Tags: msbuild

Done Building Project "C:\ProgramData\Jenkins.jenkins\workspace\TimetrackerAPI\TimeTracker.sln" (default targets).

Build succeeded.

"C:\ProgramData\Jenkins.jenkins\workspace\TimetrackerAPI\TimeTracker.sln" (default target) (1) ->
"C:\ProgramData\Jenkins.jenkins\workspace\TimetrackerAPI\src\TimeTracker.API\TimeTracker.API.csproj.metaproj" (default target) (2) ->
(Build target) ->
C:\ProgramData\Jenkins.jenkins\workspace\TimetrackerAPI\src\TimeTracker.API\TimeTracker.API.csproj.metaproj : warning MSB4078: **The project file "src\TimeTracker.API\TimeTracker.API.csproj" is not supported by MSBuild and cannot be built.**

How to fix this ?